# How to solve Which month has the highest number of bookings in oracle

Tags: oracle

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
    hotelNo VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
    guestNo VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    dateFrom DATE NOT NULL,
    dateTo DATE NOT NULL,
    roomNo VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Book PRIMARY KEY(hotelNo)
);
```

This is one of my data (hotelNo, roomNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo) VALUES (13,20,16,to_date('1/21/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('4/0/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));

My solution is

SELECT dateFrom, COUNT(*) TOTAL  from Booking
GROUP BY dateFrom
ORDER BY dateFrom DESC

Comment: How about giving it a try?

Comment: I tried but is not work.

Comment: SELECT dateFrom, COUNT(*) TOTAL  from Booking
GROUP BY dateFrom
ORDER BY dateFrom DESC 
limit 1;

Comment: This was my tried ,can u help me with this ?

Comment: A few things: 1. Sample data and expected output is useful to help people help you. 2. Is this Oracle or mySQL (LIMIT is not valid Oracle syntax)

Comment: What if a booking starts and ends in different months? Should this be considered for all the involved months, only the starting, only the ending?

Comment: This is Oracle, This is one of my data "INSERT INTO book(hotelNo, roomNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo) VALUES (13,20,16,to_date('1/21/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('4/0/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));" Sorry ,first time use stackoverflow

Comment: In your sample data, for which month(s) should this row be considered?

Comment: to_date('1/21/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY') should be considered ,The first one is the dateFrom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a simple approach, aggregating by year and month, ordering for the number of occurrences and keeping the row with the maximum number of occurrences.

If you have more than a month with the maximum number of occurrences, this will only give one of them.

Say you have a table like this:

```
insert into book values (1, null, date '2017-01-01', date '2017-01-01', 99);
insert into book values (2, null, date '2017-01-02', date '2017-01-01', 99);
insert into book values (3, null, date '2017-01-03', date '2017-01-01', 99);
insert into book values (4, null, date '2017-02-01', date '2017-01-01', 99);
insert into book values (5, null, date '2017-02-02', date '2017-01-01', 99);
```

This query

```
select *
from (
        select count(1),
               extract(month from dateFrom) month,
               extract(year  from dateFrom) year
        from Book
        group by extract(month from dateFrom),
                 extract(year  from dateFrom)
        order by 1 desc
    )
where rownum = 1
```

will give

```
  COUNT(1)      MONTH       YEAR
---------- ---------- ----------
         3          1       2017
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I got it